# Try to turn on apple pay capabilities using payment depute

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, payment-gateway, applepay

when Try  to  turn on apple pay capabilities  it adds the entitlements  but gives  red alert this app id is not available. Or any one can lead me through usage of apple pay with payment depute integration

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC videos? Did you read the documentation? What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: i have done everthing i have my CA deleted i think  and now when i try to create a new CA it not allows authorities to him